# MYSQL: Pull Only Words with Minimum Character length

Tags: mysql, select

how can I pull only words with maximum 50 Characters from MYSQL?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM example ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 200";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the [`CHAR_LENGTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) function in a `WHERE` constraint:

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(word) <= 50 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 200
```

`CHAR_LENGTH` returns the number of characters in the string. [`LENGTH`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_length) returns the number of bytes. It is prefeable to use `CHAR_LENGTH` if your word could contain multi-byte characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE LENGTH(column) <= 50 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 200
```

Comment: If you're going to downrate for a perfectly correct answer, leave a comment.

CHAR_LENGTH() may be multi-byte friendly, but LENGTH() works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the length() function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html